# Strip HTML tags and its contents

Tags: php, dom, tags, html, strip

I'm using DOM to parse string. I need function that strips span tags and its contents. For example, if I have:

```
This is some text that contains photo.
<span class='title'> photobyile</span>
```

I would like function to return

```
This is some text that contains photo.
```

This is what I tried:

```
    $dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($string);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $spans = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');

    foreach($spans as $span)
    {
        $naslov = $span->nodeValue; 
        echo $naslov;

        $string = preg_replace("/$naslov/", " ", $string);
    }
```

I'm aware that `$span->nodeValue` returns value of span tag and not whole tag, but I don't know how to get whole tag, together with class name.

Thanks,
Ile

Comment: If you don't need to use DOM, take a look at comments at [strip_tags](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) manual.

Comment: You can't tell strip_tags which tags should it remove, only which tags should it *not* remove.

Comment: Correct, that's why I have referred to the comments where methods for stripping tags can be found.

Comment: If not DOM than I'd have to use regular expressions. That's not what I really want :)

Comment: +1 bonus point for not parsing HTML using regex

Comment: any clue how to convert it to a string instead of echoing it so I can manipulate it further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try removing the spans directly from the DOM tree.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($string);
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('span');
while($span = $elements->item(0)) {       
   $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Instead of using echo; is there a way to save it as a string in a variable so I can manipulate it further? Thanks

Comment: @AhmadAlfy `$theVariable = $dom->saveHTML();` ... seriously you need to learn a little more PHP...

Comment: A little late to the party, but this does not remove the content for me. If I use the code above (changing `loadHTML` for `loadHTMLfile`, and `'span'` to `'link'`) all of my `<link>` tags disappear, but their content remains (i.e. `<link>http://www.something.com</link>` becomes `http://www.something.com`)

Comment: @Birrel Isn't that because [`<link>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/document-metadata.html#elementdef-link) is not a "paired" element, so the parser doesn't expect it to contain anything. Try changing your HTML to some other tag, e.g. `<a>` which should be used for links anyway.

Comment: @LukášLalinský I'm parsing XML files, they don't follow the same format as a regular web page. More specifically, I'm parsing RSS feeds - which have very loose standardization rules, so no two are ever the same. One might have `<link>...</link>`, while another might have `<link href="..." />`. It's frustrating, to say the least.

Comment: @LukášLalinský but yes, you're probably right about expecting the `<link>` tags to be self-closing, thus omitting the tail end to it. I've instead just extracted the portion that I'm interested in, and then brute-force parsing on the small chunk. It's safe and will work for now.

Comment: How to remove all tags instead of just the span tag?

Answer (score 1):

@ile - I've had that problem - it's because the index of the foreach iterator happily keeps incrementing, while calling removeChild() on the DOM also seems to remove the nodes from the DomNodeList ($spans). So for every span you remove, the nodelist shrinks one element and then gets its foreach counter incremented by one. Net result: it skips one span.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way, but this is how I did it - I moved the references from the DomNodeList to a second array, where they would not be removed by the removeChild() operation.

```
    foreach($spans as $span) {
        $nodes[] = $span;
    }
    foreach($nodes as $span) {
        $span->parentNode->removeChild($span);
    }
```

Comment: I see...
Although, I must confess I didn't know how exactly foreach loop works. Now it's bit clearer.
Thank you!