# Delete divs from html source code

Tags: php, html, formatting, code-formatting

I have html code in which are many divs, and want delete some divs from this code, it's so hard to do with  `substr()` or similar php string function, maybe are better way to do this ?

Comment: Can you use javascript, or jquery ?

Comment: why are you using server-side code for client-side functions?

Comment: @Phil and Nygma7, Why should this be client-side?  There are plenty of reasons you may want to do this server-side.

Comment: well, I guess I really don't know the situation, but I was assuming he would want some user event to change the html on the client's page, I just don't know how this could happen server-side

Comment: In server side the page is build, you can remove the divs and they will not be sended to the Client. this all depends of the situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript. Just give the divs unique id's, then you can write some simple javascript like so.

```
 document.getElementById('divid').remove();
```

**Note: Make sure the element(s) have loaded before running the remove().** - You can do this with [jquery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     document.getElementById('divid').remove();
});
```

Alertnativly, if you decide to add elements maybe some time after the document has loaded, **then** remove them, you can check to see if an element exists with the following code. (again using the jquery library), could can also use css selectors with an object, being as you're using jquery.

```
if ($("#divid").length > 0){
    $('#divid').remove();
}
```

That code can become handy, if say - You gradually add elements into the document, with like a live-comment system, you could use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), to keep checking if the element exists, and when it does, remove it.

---

If you NEED to do this with php then Brian Agnew's answer of using the [PHP HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) should solve your issue.

Comment: Interesting I will try this ;)

Comment: @TomasLietuva Use jQuery and run `$(document).ready()`
 - see other answer

Comment: Great, if you have any problems, feel free to make another comment here. If it works, I'd appreciate it being "accepted", thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

strip_tags() might be of help:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: _some divs from this code_ infers a selective delete which `strip_tags` wouldn't be helpful for (unless I misunderstand the question).

Comment: As I said it might be of help. The actual question is not very elaborative, hence vague answer :-)

Comment: But see I want remove not only tag `<div id="ex">`, but I want also remove all characters which are beside this tag, I think that `strip_tags()` is no way for my problem.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516085/strip-html-tags-and-its-contents

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you check out a [PHP HTML parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do this reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Can you elaborate further on your use case? I would do it in JS - give the divs you want to remove a class like `.remove` and then do the following in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.remove').remove()
});
```

Alternatively, parsing HTML in php and removing it there would be a way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Great opportunity to use the [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to parse the HTML.

```
$html = new DOMDocument();
$html->loadHTML($html_string);
```

Then you can use any of the available methods to find and remove the elements from the document, such as `getElementsByTagName`. Then it's a matter of removing them from `$html` and re-exporting the document (`$html->saveHTML()`)

Answer (score 0):

```
>try this.. ;)

> str_replace("<div>","") and 
> str_replace("</div>","")
```

Comment: `str_replace` and formatted HTML is **never** a good idea.