# How can I remove a link and its text from a block of HTML?

Tags: php, html-parsing

Say I have the following text

..(event description content).............
...(event description content)............

```
<A HREF="http://event.com/content" > blah blah blah </A>
```

This text is displayed from a mysql query. This text is used in two places, one where it talks about the event and has a link to register. Then I'd like to reuse this same text, but without the registration link ON the registration page itself for content. I want to delete the link, tag and the text in between. I've seen the strip_tags() function, but that keeps the text in between.

Much thanks

Comment: This will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516085/strip-html-tags-and-its-contents

Comment: I changed the title and the tags because this has nothing to do with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
preg_replace("/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/", "", $text);
```

Where `$text` is your content.

Example:

```
$text = 'Its <a href="google.com">Google</a>';
echo preg_replace("/<a href=.*?>(.*?)<\/a>/", "", $text);
```

Will simply output: `Its`