# Regex for stripping HTML tags and contents

Tags: php, html, regex

I've searched and searched and for some reason I couldn't find any solution.

This is my current text:

```
Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit <i>amet</i>.
```

This is what I want:

```
Lorem ipsum sit.
```

I **do not** want to use an HTML parser. I just want to use a simple regex to remove HTML tags and their inner content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though @Tommy's answer works for you, that `regex` is really much too complicated for what you want to do. *You can simply do this:*

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum <strong>dolor</strong> sit <i>amet</i>.";

$r = preg_replace("/ <\S*>/", "", $str);

echo $r;
#=> Lorem ipsum sit.
```

Comment: Nice. I just took a regexp from the notes on the documentation for strip_tags(). This looks way nicer.

Answer (score 1):

This regular expression used with the global flag will match html-tags and text inside html-tags.

```
<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>[A-Za-z0-9.,;:]*<[\/\!]*?[^<>]*?>
```

Comment: `strip_tags` just unwraps the content. I want the content gone as well.

Comment: Your question has already been answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1516085/strip-html-tags-and-its-contents

Comment: Both answers use HTML parsers, something I don't want to use.

Comment: Edited the answer with a regular expression for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/(<.*?>)|(&.*?;)/', '', $string)
```

This one works pretty well for me. It strips all the HTML tags and special HTML characters. Hope this helps.